# Asp .Net framework 3.5 Sitemap.CurrentNode returns null When using URL Rewriting with parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, null, url-parameters

I'm using Asp .Net framework 3.5, SiteMap And URL Rewriting with Global.asax.
Everything works except when I passing parameters in the Url (for example MySite/Products/Some-Spesific-TV)

The SiteMap is built like this:

```
< siteMapNode url="Product" title=""  description="" resourceKey="1011"/>
```

And the URL Rewriting is built like this (in the Global.asax file):

```
routes.Add("Product" + "/{ProductID}", new Route("Product"+ "/{ProductID}", new CustomRouteHandler("~/" + "Product" + ".aspx")));
```

When trying to use Sitemap.CurrentNode On "Product/SomeValue" it returns null

What can I do?